# Camel: Is it Possible to Implement Request/Reply & Competing Consumers with the Help of Asynchronous Processor?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm struggling with the implementation of a **Request/Reply** exchange that should be processed concurrently by several **Competing Consumers**.

I have one standalone **Master**-module that is responsible for producing a queue of *tasks*. And I have many **Worker**-modules that should consume messages from that queue concurrently.

This is the **Master**-part of the Camel routing:

```java
from("direct:start")
.to("log:FROM.DIRECT?level=DEBUG")
.split(body()).setHeader(CamelHeader.TASKS_BATCH_ID, simple("BATCH-1"))
.setHeader(CamelHeader.TASK_TYPE, simple(TaskType.FETCH_INDEX))
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        EdgarFullIndexLocation location = 
            exchange.getIn().getBody(EdgarFullIndexLocation.class);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(location.getId().toJson(), String.class);
    }
})
.to("log:SPLIT?level=DEBUG")
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.to("activemq:queue:tasksQueue?replyTo=completionsQueue" +
    //"&transactedInOut=true" + 
    "&requestTimeout=" + Integer.MAX_VALUE +
    "&disableTimeToLive=true")
.threads(10)
.to("log:RESPONSE?level=DEBUG")
.routeId(routeId);
```

This is the **Worker** part of the Camel routing, where I consume the queue:

```java
from("activemq:queue:tasksQueue?asyncConsumer=true" + 
    "&concurrentConsumers=10")
.to("log:FROM.TASKS.QUEUE?level=DEBUG")
.choice()
    .when(header(CamelHeader.TASK_TYPE).isEqualTo(TaskType.FETCH_INDEX))
        .process(new FetchIndexTaskProcessor())
    .otherwise()
        .to("log:UNKNOWN.TASK?level=DEBUG");
```

Here the **FetchIndexTaskProcessor** implements **AsyncProcessor**:

```java
public class FetchIndexTaskProcessor implements AsyncProcessor {
    @Override public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback) {
        FetchIndexTask task = new FetchIndexTask(exchange, callback);
        task.start();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here the **FetchIndexTask** extends **Thread**. After **start()** the new thread is responsible for:

1. Dynamically adding a route.
2. Blocking until the exchange of that route completes.
3. Preparing a reply to the original exchange.
4. Calling `callback.done(false);` at the end.

Everything works, except for the part of having **Competing Consumers** - it is always a single consumer at a time.

I have tried many options like:

- specifying a thread pool with `.threads(10)` in various places.
- using endpoint options such as `asyncConsumer` and `concurrentConsumers`

But it seems like I'm missing something important, and I can't seem to make it work in a concurrent fashion. What is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: I've tried using 5.6-SNAPSHOT release of ActiveMQ with the new destination options, but I had no luck with `destination.consumer.dispatchAsync=true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Camel 2.9 or better, then I suggest to use replyToType=Exclusive on the activemq endpoint where you do request/reply. This tells Camel that the queue is exclusive, and it speedup, as no JMS message selectors is needed to pickup expected correlated messages.

See the section *Request-reply over JMS* onwards at the Camel JMS docs: http://camel.apache.org/jms

If you use temporary queues, then that is also fast as well, as no JMS message selectors is needed.

Also your route starts with a direct endpoint. That is a synchronous call, so the caller will wait/block until the Exchange is completely done.

Also the Splitter EIP can be configured to run in parallel mode which will use concurrent processing. And if you have a big message to split, then consider using streaming which will split the message on-demand, instead of loading the entire message content into memory.

Anyway there is a lot going on in the route.
Can you pin-point more precisely where you have an issue? It makes it easier to help out.

Comment: `split(...).parallelProcessing()` - this is it!